# chrome.experimental.processes.onExited.addListener not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a Chrome extension which detects process crashes.

First i went to `about:flags` page of Chrome and enabled "Experimental Extension APIs".

This is the extension I wrote:

`manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "CrashDetect",
  "description": "Detects crashes in processes.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "experimental","tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

`backround.js`:

```
chrome.experimental.processes.onExited.addListener(function(integer processId, integer  exitType, integerexitCode) {
  chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(Tab tab) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url:"http:\\127.0.0.1\""});
  };)
});
```

Then I visited `about://crash` page of Chrome. But `onExited` listener does not execute.
Have I done anything wrong in `manifest.json` or `background.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a couple errors in your code. First you have the types of the parameters in the function declaration, change it to:

```
function(processId, exitType, integerexitCode){
```

Second, you put `};)` instead of `});`. Try [inspecting the background page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029/720450) to see syntax errors.

---

Alright, after playing around with it some as I was unfamiliar with this particular API, I found that none of the events fired if I didn't include a handler for `onUpdated`. I really doubt that this is the intended behavior and I will check to see if there is a bug report on it. For now just do something like this to get it working:

```
chrome.experimental.processes.onUpdated.addListener(function(process){});

chrome.experimental.processes.onExited.addListener(function(processId, exitType, integerexitCode){
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow:true},function(tabs){
      chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url:"http:\\127.0.0.1"});
    });
});
```

Notice that I did swap out your `getCurrent` for a `chrome.tabs.query` as the former would have given you an error. This does lead to the behavior of if you close a tab, the next tab will be redirected. Perhaps you could try to filter by `exitType` and not include normal exits.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected errors in background.js. But still onExit listener does not execute.

Comment: @chamaldesilva I updated my answer with what I believe to be a solution to your problem.